# Test various TDS versions

Tags: sql-server, testing

We have a service that works with various versions of Microsoft SQL Server. For each version, we have different implementations, including different TDS versions. I need to implement tests that simulate working with different TDS versions.

What it the best way to implement such tests? Should I write my own client?